# How do I completely wipe Cuda and CudNN off my ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, uninstall, cuda

[Removing nvidia cuda toolkit and installing new one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530043/removing-nvidia-cuda-toolkit-and-installing-new-one)

Followed everything from the above link but I still have cuda and cuda-9.1 folder in my /usr/local/ directory?

Answer (score 4):

**The official NVIDIA CUDA installation guide gives a similar but more complete method:**

To remove CUDA Toolkit:

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove "*cuda*" "*cublas*" "*cufft*" "*cufile*" "*curand*" "*cusolver*" "*cusparse*" "*gds-tools*" "*npp*" "*nvjpeg*" "nsight*"
```

To remove NVIDIA Drivers:

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove "*nvidia*"
```

To clean up the uninstall:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

(See here for more details: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands if you haven't already

```
sudo apt-get --purge -y remove 'cuda*'
sudo apt-get --purge -y remove 'nvidia*
```

after this I ran the command below and it did the trick for me

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge cuda
```