# Is my Cuda installation a mess?

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, cuda

I'm trying to make Cuda work with a second GPU that I have recently added to my workstation rig.

When I used to download and install Cuda in my computer, I had the Nvidia NVS 315 GPU. Now, I've added a Quadro P400 GPU, and I'm looking to install the latest Cuda version for it to leverage it for accelerated computing while running Deep Learning algorithms (Caffe2 for instance). However, I don't know what to start with.

Check the following outputs :

**nvidia-smi**

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.111                Driver Version: 384.111                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVS 315             Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| 30%   45C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    255MiB /   956MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Quadro P400         Off  | 00000000:05:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 34%   34C    P8   ERR! /  N/A |      1MiB /  1999MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                    Not Supported                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**nvcc --version**

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
```

**which nvcc**

```
/usr/bin/nvcc
```

**ldconfig -p | grep cuda**

```
libnvToolsExt.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvToolsExt.so.1
libnvToolsExt.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvToolsExt.so
libicudata.so.55 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55
libicudata.so.55 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55
libicudata.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so
libcudart.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so.9.0
libcudart.so.7.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so.7.5
libcudart.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so
libcuda.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
libcuda.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
libcuda.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
libcuda.so (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
```

I want to make my algorithms select the second GPU (Quadro P400) for accelerated computing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my question, yes it's a mess (it was).

I completely removed Cuda by following the instructions found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/530050/454331) (uninstalling cuda with its dependencies), then I installed Cuda 9.0 by following the instructions contained [here](https://yangcha.github.io/CUDA90/) (you can skip the uninstallation part if you did it properly before).

After that, in order to install the Cuda libraries within a virtual environment set by Conda and install within the Caffe2 library, I followed the following instructions:

- [Setting up of a virtual env](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/318719/292868)
- [Installing Cuda libraries](https://developer.nvidia.com/how-to-cuda-python)
- Installing the Caffe2 library compatible with Cuda 9.0

> conda install -c caffe2 caffe2-cuda9.0-cudnn7