# Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install'

Tags: drivers, nvidia, dependencies, cuda

The problem arised when i tried to uninstall the `cuda-10.0` toolkit from my system using the following method mentioned in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530043/removing-nvidia-cuda-toolkit-and-installing-new-one) by user271219.

1) My Nvidia driver

```
$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version

NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  387.26  Thu Nov  2 21:20:16 PDT 2017
GCC version:  gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9)
```

2) Trying to remove `cuda-10-0`

```
$ sudo apt-get purge cuda-10-0 

You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-cudart-dev-10-0 : Depends: cuda-driver-dev-10-0 (>= 10.0.130) but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-libraries-dev-10-0 : Depends: cuda-driver-dev-10-0 (>= 10.0.130) but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-samples-10-0 : Depends: cuda-driver-dev-10-0 but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-toolkit-10-0 : Depends: cuda-nvml-dev-10-0 (>= 10.0.130) but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-visual-tools-10-0 : Depends: cuda-driver-dev-10-0 (>= 10.0.130) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: cuda-nvml-dev-10-0 (>= 10.0.130) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

3) Forcing the `apt-get`

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f

The following additional packages will be installed:
  cuda-driver-dev-10-0 cuda-nvml-dev-10-0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cuda-driver-dev-10-0 cuda-nvml-dev-10-0
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 189 not upgraded.
10 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/63.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 556 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48  cuda-driver-dev-10-0 10.0.130-1 [12.0 kB]
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48  cuda-nvml-dev-10-0 10.0.130-1 [51.6 kB]
(Reading database ... 123484 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../cuda-driver-dev-10-0_10.0.130-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-driver-dev-10-0 (10.0.130-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48/./cuda-driver-dev-10-0_10.0.130-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64', which is also in package cuda-npp-10-0 10.0.130-1
Preparing to unpack .../cuda-nvml-dev-10-0_10.0.130-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-nvml-dev-10-0 (10.0.130-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48/./cuda-nvml-dev-10-0_10.0.130-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64', which is also in package cuda-npp-10-0 10.0.130-1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48/./cuda-driver-dev-10-0_10.0.130-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48/./cuda-nvml-dev-10-0_10.0.130-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I want to get my system clean from the current `cuda` files and reinstall it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted the repositories related to cuda

```
$ rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda*
```

updated the repositories using `apt-get update`

Purged all the files related to cuda

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove cuda*
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Problem solved.