# CUDA version shown but nvcc compiler not found

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

On Ubuntu 16.04 with Quadro K1000M, I have installed the Nvidia GPU driver version 418.56 from `Software & Updates->Additional Driver`. When I check `nvidia-smi` it shows

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.56       Driver Version: 418.56       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

which clearly shows the CUDA version 10.1. However, when I check `nvcc --version`, the terminal shows

```
The program 'nvcc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

which seems to suggest the CUDA compiler is missing. Meanwhile, there is no CUDA directory, such as `cuda-10-0` or something similar, created inside `/usr/local`. If I simply follow `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`, would I get the older version such 7.5? Ran this command before, but I actually got an old version 7.5, instead of 10.

Also downloaded the specific version of the toolkit from http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads and installed manually by running

```
sudo sh cuda_10.2.89_440.33.01_linux.run
```

it complained

```
Existing package manager installation of the driver found. It is strongly recommended that you remove this before continuing
```

Then I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530043/removing-nvidia-cuda-toolkit-and-installing-new-one) on how to remove the older version of CUDA. First of all, I don't have any directory such as `/usr/local/cuda-5.0` or alike. Second, if I follow the advanced step suggested in the post then rerun `sudo sh cuda_10.2.89_440.33.01_linux.run`, it complains that there is no driver installed.

Now I don't know what am I supposed to do. Help will be highly appriated.

**Note**

The `gcc` version is 5.4 on my system.

Comment: nvidia-smi shows the latest cuda version compatible with your driver, not the cuda version installed